# How do I save archive from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml, backup

I have a database in SQL Server. Basically, table consists of a number of XML documents that represent same table data at given time (like backup history). What is the best method to cut off all the old (3 months) backups, remove from DB and save them archived?

[image: Table structure]

Comment: try to add content as text , instead of image. persons can copy data and try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no export out of the box in SQL Server.

Assuming

- Your table can be pretty big, since it looks like you and image of the table every minute.
- If you want to do it all from inside SQL Server.

Then I'll suggest doing cleanup in chunks.
The usual process in SQL to delete by chunks is using DELETE in combination with OUTPUT statement. 
The easiest way to archive and remove then would be having the OUTPUT to a table in another database, for that sole purpose.

so your steps would be:

1. Create a new database (*ArchiveDatabase*)
2. Create an Archive table in *ArchiveDatabase* (ArchiveTable) with same structure of the table that you want to remove.
3. In a while loop perform the DELETE/OUTPUT
4. Backup the *ArchiveDatabase*
5. TRUNCATE *ArchiveTable* table in *ArchiveDatabase*

The DELETE/OUTPUT loops will look like something like

```
declare @RowsToDelete int = 1000 
declare @DeletedRowsCNT int = 1000 

while @DeletedRowsCNT = @RowsToDelete 
begin 
    delete top (@RowsToDelete) 
    from MyDataTable
    output deleted.* into ArchiveDatabase.dbo.ArchiveTable
    where dt < dateadd(month, 3, getdate())
    set @DeletedRowsCNT = @@ROWCOUNT
end
```